# Partitioning for dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, uefi, ssd

My motherboard is a Asus am1l-a with a uefi bios. I have a 120 gb ssd and a 3tb hdd I plan on adding another 3tb hdd. I plan on installing Ubuntu as my main os and Arch as a secondary just for messing around with. This is primarily going to be a htpc and will store most of my music and movies. It will also be a small Minecraft server for at most four of my friends and I. My question is, what would you recommend as a partitioning scheme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. All of the `/home` on HDD, OS on SSD
2. At a minimum, split your `/` from your `/home` for your "production" OS (Ubuntu). If you want to split even more have a look at the **[FHS](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_2.3/)**.  64GB `/`, 2TB `/home`
3. One swap partition for both OSes (Minimum size = RAM, Max size=RAM*2)
4. If Arch is to mess around with, 32GB `/`, 512 GB `/home`
5. Yes, not all of your disk space is allocated: just keep that as 'spare' to move & extend existing partitions if needed. (or `bcache` the HDDs)
6. [Some other possibilities](https://askubuntu.com/questions/581902/how-to-efficiently-partition-a-single-windows-ubuntu-dual-boot-disk)

**Freebies you didn't ask for:**

1. If you plan on adding another 3TB drive: **Don't use software RAID!**  It's prone to software and hardware errors so divide your [MTBF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_time_between_failures) by 2 for 1 OS and by 4 for 2 OSes
2. If you plan to use hardware RAID: Don't use RAID0: divide your MTBF by 2 if you do.
3. Make frequent [system back-ups](https://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc) (You're definitely user type 4)