# no partition after installing ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation, boot-repair, mbr

I cannot boot back my windows 8 disk after Ubuntu install.

I installed Ubuntu. Probably I selected my main disk (I wanted to used the diskonkey disk). After about 3-4 screens (selecting time zone) I noticed that is using the wrong partition and I powered down the laptop.

Now I don’t have a partition table with windows 8. It cannot boot. I think I have to recover my MBR and partition table.

I used the boot repair - this is what it showed: http://paste.ubuntu.com/9659707/

Comment: The device you call "my main disk" is, apparently, not present. Is the device connected?

Comment: Windows 8 preloaded computers come with a GPT disklabel. Reboot using UEFI boot and attach the results of `sudo blkid` and `sudo gdisk -l` from a terminal.

Comment: Partition table was erased before you stopped process. You may be able to use testdisk to restore gpt partitions. http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk

Comment: Thanks Erkin, how should i boot using UEFI boot? Is it with the same linux/ubuntu disk? or some other tool?

Comment: UEFI boot uses GRUB on Ubuntu LiveCD. EFI system partition has to be first and FAT16/32 formatted or otherwise Windows 8 GUI bootloader will create a new one on its own. You should do a `sudo grub-install --uefi-secure-boot <target>` on LiveCD and `sudo apt install grub-efi-amd64` on your Ubuntu installation.

Answer (score 0):

*Powering down in the middle of an installation because you've taken the wrong choice is always the worst decision you can take.  **That is like powering down your car in the middle of a busy cross-road because you took a wrong turn.***  (Just believe me: don't try this!)

The **easiest** way to solve this situation is to:

1. Enable UEFI in the BIOS and reboot.
2. If that didn't work, take the recovery DVD that came with your machine and boot with that to get your system back.  **Warning** this will destroy all of your data still remaining on the drive. (You *did make* [a back-up](https://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc) before starting the install didn't you?)

The **more difficult** way:

1. Attach your back-up drive to the computer
2. Boot with the Ubuntu LiveCD
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install testdisk
   testdisk
   ```
4. Follow  [testdisk step-by-step](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step) instructions to save as much of your data as possible.
5. Recover using the Recovery DVD
6. Follow these instructions on [how to efficiently partition a Windows-Ubuntu dual-boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/581902/how-to-efficiently-partition-a-single-windows-ubuntu-dual-boot-disk) and [how to install Ubuntu on a pre-installed Windows 8 machine](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported).