# change default paths of (Music, Pictures, Temples, installations, ECT)

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, paths

I have my 250GB HDD split up into 3 partitions.  25GB has a windows 7 installation. 25GB has Ubuntu 14.04. 200GB is simply an empty NTFS partition.  I have done in the past with windows instaltions where I have the same thing set up to where all my picture, videos, music, programs, templets, and ECT all goto/install to that 200GB partition.  I simply want to change my default paths in Ubuntu to do the same thing but can't figure out how.  This way when I go to open up pictures, videos, and music it will open up the same location on the 200GB parttion as I have it set to do in Windows.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to efficiently partition a single Windows-Ubuntu dual boot disk?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/581902/how-to-efficiently-partition-a-single-windows-ubuntu-dual-boot-disk)

Comment: Can you describe your current and desired setup more in detail please? Some (exemplary) path names would be useful to help readers understand your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use symbolic linking.

First, you need to mount your 200Gb partition, if that has not already happened. You need to use the `mount` command to mount the partition manually; if that goes well, you may want to edit `/etc/fstab` to have the partition automatically mounted at reboot.

Suppose the partition is mounted at `/media/largedisk`, and that all your music is stored in `/media/largedisk/Music/`. Then, move everything in `/home/youruser/Music` out of the way so that it is empty, then remove the empty directory: `rmdir /home/youruser/Music`. Now, create a link to the new partition: `ln -s /media/largedisk/Music /home/youruser/Music`. Now everytime you use the folder `/home/youruser/Music`, you will in fact be addressing the Music directory on the other partition. To remove this, simply `rm /home/youruser/Music`: this will only remove the link, not the Music folder on the other partition.

Then repeat for videos, photos, etc.