# External hdd ubuntu format

Tags: external-hdd, format

I'm about to partition my ext. hdd, in 2 parts. The first part will be MacOSX formated. 
I want the second partition to read/write both Ubuntu and Windows.
Will NTFS do it for me?

Comment: You need 3 partitions.One for Mac OS X.One for Windows(NTFS) and one for Linux(Ext4)

Comment: @MarvinMicek. No you don't. NTFS will be fine.

Comment: The truth is that I will install Ubuntu for the first time in my life, so I don't think that I would transfer a big amount of data, so I also think NTFS should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

**You *cannot* install Ubuntu onto an NTFS partition, as [NTFS does not support permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11305463/ntfs-as-root-file-system).**

But if you are just storing data, NTFS is fine and both Ubuntu and Windows can read/write from/to it.

Just in case you want something that is supported by all three platforms, check out the [UDF filesystem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/59585/file-system-compatible-with-all-oses).

EDIT: As mentioned by user Fabby, [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/581903/145754) details how you can actually achieve running Ubuntu and Windows on the same NTFS partition. I absolutely would not recommend it though, unless you *really* know what you are doing.

Comment: Jmiserez: It is possible, just [very complicated](http://askubuntu.com/questions/581902/how-to-efficiently-partition-a-single-windows-ubuntu-dual-boot-disk)  So your answer is best for a beginner!  ;-) (So I upvoted!)

Comment: @Fabby Wow, that is some crazy stuff. I've added it to my answer.

Comment: :D  Luckily I didn't respond to your first comment as I was reviewing duplicate answers...  We live and we learn!  ;-)  Actually UDF should be included in my Q&A!  So we both learned smtg today!  (I never thought of that!  I'm going to test it out when I find my |@#^ USB stick!)

Comment: Once I saw that you yourself wrote all the answers I was a fair bit embarrassed :-/ Thanks for sharing the knowledge!