# Windows File Permissions

Tags: partitioning, permissions

I just faced a weird issue where my windows laptop hard drive encountered an I/O error. The C:/ partition became entirely inaccessible via any Windows based machine, the D:/ partition however was accessible. The C:/ partition is accessible to me via Ubuntu-based machine, and I can see the files within that partition as well. However the files within my user account for in that partition aren't visible at all, presumably because of Windows Permissions. Is there any way to modify these permissions so I can at least recover my files? 
Thanks for your kind cooperation.
Aamir.

Comment: Yes...  If [you're a Windows and an Ubuntu expert](http://askubuntu.com/questions/581902/how-to-efficiently-partition-a-single-windows-ubuntu-dual-boot-disk)