# Windows 8.1 not booting after Ubuntu 14.04 Installation

Tags: 14.04, boot, grub2, windows

I'm an absolute Linux newbie, I've never used it before.
I've just installed Ubuntu 14.04 on the same hard drive with Windows 8.1.
When I choose a Windows 8 Loader in the Grub Loader screen, nothing happens.

When I tried to fix Boot Loader using Boot-Repair utility, nothing changed:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo sh -c "sed -i 's/trusty/saucy/g' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yannubuntu-boot-repair-trusty.list"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

I also used Boot-Repair utility to [generate a paste from Boot-repair](http://paste.ubuntu.com/10653601/).

I tried using `sudo update-grub`, offered by the_Seppi. The things changed a bit. 
Now, when choosing Windows 8 Loader in the Grub menu, I see a blank black screen, but Windows itself is not loading.

What should I do?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Have you tried running `sudo update-grub`?

Comment: @the_Seppi I'm not sure if I tried this before, but I've just done `sudo update-grub`. The things changed. Now, when I select Windows 8 Loader in the Grub, it takes me to a black blank screen with a blinking cursor in the top left corner. But Windows 8 doesn't boot.

Comment: @the_Seppi, I repeated Boot-Repair utility configuration commands, utility generated the new Boot-Repair paste:  http://paste.ubuntu.com/10653601/

Comment: In the future, please [edit] your question to keep all information in one spot. (already done for you)...  :P  ;-)
What happens if you do a Windows boot-repair (boot Windows CD).  Does that boot Windows then?  Afterwards, do an Ubuntu boot-repair (boot that CD)

Comment: @Fabby, thanks for your advice! Recently, I talked to a few folks on another thread here: [link](http://forum.ubuntu.ru/index.php?topic=259028.0). They told me that the model of my Laptop (Sony Vaio VGN-FW21MR) may not be compatible for dual boot, although it has not been proven yet. There was a case when Sony Vaio Pro 13 [link](http://forum.ubuntu.ru/index.php?topic=244456.0;all) -- a Laptop without a "UEFI" BIOS feature -- had exactly the same problem.

Comment: My Laptop lacks UEFI too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This tutorial article helped me to install Ubuntu 16.04 + Windows 10 on one drive on my old laptop (Sony Vaio VGN-FW21MR) mentioned above.

Link to article: 
http://www.tecmint.com/install-ubuntu-16-04-alongside-with-windows-10-or-8-in-dual-boot/

Issue resolved.

Comment: Although tour answer is 100% correct, it might also become 100% useless if that link is moved, deleted or the site that you link to just disappears.  Therefore, please copy the relevant steps from the link into your answer so your answer remains valid for the lifetime of this site!  **;-)**

Answer (score 0):

If you have a laptop and your Windows is preintalled, you need to enable in bios "UEFI Boot". All the good!

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. No, I don't have a preinstalled Windows, I re-installed it multiple times. I cannot see UEFI Boot option either, but the Boot Priority List and the Network Boot flag.

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you don't have an UEFI boot partition, but I don't like the "unknown" partition, so the easiest thing to do for you now is:

1. Boot an Ubuntu LiveDVD
2. Make a [full system backup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc) *and* a data backup!
3. re-install Windows using 2 drives: a 64 GB System drive and a ensuring it only takes maximum 180 GB Data drive
4. Re-install Ubuntu and create a 32 GB `/`, `swap` equal to your RAM and `/home` partition of everything else minus 8GB under EXT4 and an 8 GB FAT partition to exchange data between Ubuntu and Windows
5. if all works, restore the data (Documents, Pictures, ...).  Don't restore the configuration settings to have a clean system!  **;-)**

Alternatively, you could create a [more advanced partitioning scheme](https://askubuntu.com/questions/581902/how-to-efficiently-partition-a-single-windows-ubuntu-dual-boot-disk)

Comment: thank you for the solution offered, the time spent to write this answer and sorry for the long delayed answer. I couldn't test the solution you offered, because I have re-installed everything, so I'm not able to check whether it is right or wrong.

Comment: This tutorial helped me to install  Ubuntu 16.04 + Windows 10 on one drive on my old laptop (Sony Vaio VGN-FW21MR) mentioned above.  Link: http://www.tecmint.com/install-ubuntu-16-04-alongside-with-windows-10-or-8-in-dual-boot/

Comment: @HappyTorturer: you should post that as an answer instead of editing your question!  **;-)**