# I can access the files on the D (Data) drive from both Ubuntu and Windows

Tags: dual-boot, shared-folders

I installed Ubuntu yesterday. 
When I just had Windows, I stored some files on the D drive and now that I've installed Ubuntu as well, I can access these files from both operating systems.
From what I've seen online, this is not the norm. It looks like people usually need to do a lot of fiddling around to be able to share documents between OSs.

Is my situation anything to be worried about?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to mount Windows (NTFS) filesystem due to hibernation](http://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation)

Comment: @Mr.Gosh No... this person **can**...

Answer (score 1):

It is supposed to be this way. NTFS partitions can be accessed by both Ubuntu and Windows.

The problem you may have seen that NTFS can't be accessed after Windows is hibernated, that is what Windows 8 does on exiting by default.

Answer (score 0):

Most people don't have a D-drive under Windows, so that's why they can't access their data easily.  Because of your foresight in creating an additional data drive, Ubuntu's intelligence kicks in, mounts the drive automatically and you see what you see.

So it's a bit of both worlds: Ubuntu *and you*…

For more info, [read here...](https://askubuntu.com/questions/581902/how-to-efficiently-partition-a-single-windows-ubuntu-dual-boot-disk)

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**