# Ubuntu 20.04 not booting after label change

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, boot-repair

I changed the label of ubuntu partition in windows 10 and now it is not booting up.

[![here is the image of boot screen][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHWCJ.jpg

Please help !!

I see these lines with read mark in gparted

```
dumpe2fs: Superblock checksum does not match superblock while trying to open /dev/sda

The following list of software pavkages is required for ext4 file system support: e2fsprogs v1.41+.
```

Comment: What Windows tool did you use to alter your Ubuntu partition?

Comment: MiniTool Partition Wizard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the MiniTool Partition wizard corrupted my /dev/sda2 which results in not able to boot

I booted from live usb of ubuntu or you can use live usb of gparted and saw a warning sign on /dev/sd2. On its information it was saying `packages required for ext4 file system support e2fsprogs v1.41+`

So I did this [The installer needs to remove operating system files from the install target, but was unable to do so. The install cannot continue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/640903/the-installer-needs-to-remove-operating-system-files-from-the-install-target-bu) and the warning sign was gone

Now I am able boot from /dev/sda2