# Can't get Ubuntu to dual boot with windows 8.1

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I've been trying for a few days to get this to work but I can't get both Ubuntu 14.04.2 to dual boot with Windows 8.1.  These are the steps I followed:

1. Install Windows and during installation I convert the harddrive to GPT
2. try to install Ubuntu and it still doesn't say install next to Windows and doesn't show any of my partitions.

I made 3 partitions, one for Windows, one for Ubuntu and another for games and such. I tried booting in UEFI and BIOS mode and none of it works.

This is my first time using Ubuntu so I'm not familiar with all of the workings but I read somewhere that I needed my harddrive in `GPT` format so that's what I did.

**Specs:**

- Fx8320
- Asus m5a99fx pro r2.0
- 8gb gskill 1866mhz ram
- 2tb wd green
- Thermaltake 650w psu
- Hd Radeon 7790
- Gtx 750ti (took it out during Ubuntu install due to it not working without drivers) yes I run them together due to one controlling another monitor.

The output of `sudo gparted --list` is:

```
Warning: /dev/sda contains GPT signatures, indicating that it has a GPT table. 
However, it does not have a valid fake msdos partition table, as it should. 
Perhaps it was corrupted -- possibly by a program that doesn't understand GPT partition tables. 
Or perhaps you deleted the GPT table, and are now using an msdos partition table. 
Is this a GPT partition table? 

Yes/No?
```

*How should I proceed?*

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **;-)** What version of Ubuntu?  Have you tried `mbt`  in BIOS mode yet?  Please [edit] your answer and add this info.  Furthermore, please read [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/581902/how-to-efficiently-partition-a-single-windows-ubuntu-dual-boot-disk) on how to correctly partition dual boots.

Comment: Warning: /dev/sda contains GPT signatures, indicating that it has a GPT table.
However, it does not have a valid fake msdos partition table, as it should.
Perhaps it was corrupted -- possibly by a program that doesn't understand GPT
partition tables.  Or perhaps you deleted the GPT table, and are now using an
msdos partition table.  Is this a GPT partition table?
Yes/No?

Comment: Please delete all comments.  Answer coming up!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just press <kbd>Y</kbd> on the `sudo gparted --list` question and install again...

That will solve your problem …

Comment: I have one more question. Why does my partitions I made in windows show on the "try" version of ubuntu but not during the install?

Comment: Because the install is *very* careful and if it doesn't find everything beautiful-and-clean, the only option you have is to wipe the entire mess or not install...  **;-)** (Or you can post a question on Ask Ubuntu where we'll clean up the mess manually for you!) **:D**

Answer (score 0):

In my general experience (I've recently moved to Ubuntu as my sole OS), it shouldn't matter too much about formatting the hard drive before installing Ubuntu. You can create your partition as part of the installation process. So, my advice would be: Install Windows first, then install Ubuntu and create the partition as part of the install.

Comment: I was in the try mode of u Ubuntu and it shows all the partitions I made when installing windows. I was go through a list of solutions before I used yours and I stumbled apon this. How come it doesn't show in the install process?

Comment: I'm sorry, perhaps I'm not understanding you properly... What exactly doesn't show in the install process?