# how I can rearrange my partitions?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, mount

I need help with this problem!
I would like to install windows and ubuntu in the same hard disk.
My plan was to have Windows on a partition, install ubuntu on another partition, one for ubuntu files and finally the largest partition to store all my data and shared with windows and ubuntu (NTFS)
The problem arose when it reaches the limit allowed partitions because the "/boot" partition was created.
now I have most of my hard disk unusable, as it will not create any partitions me with her.
I could do to resolve this?
I can merge it into the Windows partition to create the new partition?

my current partitioning scheme

```
/dev/sda1 - NTFS - /boot  - 200Mb
/dev/sda2 - NTFS - /Windows  - 95Gb
/dev/sda3 - ext4 - / - 14Gb
/dev/sda4 - ext4 - extended - 80Gb
/dev/sda5 - ext4 - /usr
/dev/sda6 - ext4 - /home
/dev/sda7 - linux-swap
Unassigned - 507 Gb
```

Thank you!

Gparted: 
[image]

Comment: I have Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 7

Comment: Please add a link to a gparted screenshot. And also I do not recommend to have separate `/boot` and `/usr` partitions for a desktop system.

Comment: Expand the extended sda4 to include all the unallocated. Usually better with Linux to have / (root), swap, /home and shared NTFS data. And if putting all your data in the shared NTFS, you may not need /home as a partition but just inside /  as 25GB or so. http://askubuntu.com/questions/581902/how-to-efficiently-partition-a-single-windows-ubuntu-dual-boot-disk

Comment: that's what I wanted to do but cant do because of /boot partition .
/usr and /home are inside of the extended partition sda4
Just upload a photo of my current partition gparted show distribution .
Thank!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like Ubuntu is already installed. And you have no separate `/boot` partition.

If Ubuntu works with this installation, you can leave it as it is.

If you boot from LiveCD, turn off swap by running

```
sudo swapoff -a
```

you will be able to expand `/dev/sda4` right and create an NTFS partition inside of it.

You cannot create one more primary partition because you already have 4 of them. But there is no problem to create another logical partition.

But I recommend to remove a separate `/usr` partition and re-install Ubuntu using only `/`, `/home` and `swap` partitions.

Comment: I did it!
with LiveCD  I managed to move the empty space to the extended partition and create an NTFS partition!
thank you! =D