# Unable to access password protected folder on Windows share

Tags: windows, permissions, samba, sharing

I'm able to connect to the Windows share via both the GUI and command line - the share itself does not require credentials, but the folder I am trying to access is limited by username/pw. When I try to open this folder, Ubuntu returns that I don't have permission to access this folder (which is true) but does not prompt me for credentials.

Running 14.04 LTS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connecting to the server in the format smb://user@sharename prompted me for a domain and password, and I was able to gain access to the share. Hurray!

Answer (score 1):

Windows and Ubuntu have completely different security architectures (Ubuntu being the more secure one) so it just refuses to open the folder (=directory).

The correct way of doing this under Ubuntu is to give permissions on that directory to a group and have you as a member of that group and then you will be able to open this.

As this is a Windows share, you need to read up on the NTFS permissions [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/581903/344926) and synchronise both Ubuntu and Windows users using the advanced options of the ntfs-3g driver.

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Comment: Thank you for the feedback - this share is controlled by my enterprise admin and linux systems are relatively new, so I'm thinking this is a little over my head for the time being. to ask a follow up - would it be possible to connect to the share via a Windows machine that already has access? Ie, connect to the windows machine and access the share through its file system?

Comment: That's totally off-topic here: *a Windows answer!* **;-)** But creating a share separate for that directory on another Windows machine with the right credentials where you then connect to from Ubuntu *might* work, but will be 2* slower.  However, I deleted my Windows about two years ago now and can't test this for you any more...  If the above crazy idea doesn't work, go to http://superuser.com where you will find people still using Windows! (Sorry, that's the best I can do for you right now)