# dualboot doesn't recognize windows 7

Tags: system-installation

I would like to dual-boot Windows 7 and Ubuntu and have reserved 2 partitions for that purpose.

But when I boot de Ubuntu LiveDVD, it doesn't recognize Windows and wants to install Ubuntu on the entire drive.

Output of `parted --list`:

```
Model: ATA Hitachi HDS72101 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start   End     Size   File system  Name                          Flags
 1      1049kB  106MB   105MB  fat32        EFI system partition          boot
 2      106MB   240MB   134MB               Microsoft reserved partition  msftres
 3      240MB   315GB   315GB  ntfs         Basic data partition          msftdata
 4      315GB   629GB   314GB  ntfs         Basic data partition          msftdata
 5      629GB   1000GB  371GB  ntfs         Basic data partition          msftdata


Warning: Unable to open /dev/sr0 read-write (Read-only file system).  /dev/sr0
has been opened read-only.
Error: Can't have a partition outside the disk!
```

*How can I install Ubuntu next to Windows 7 and dual boot?*

Comment: all of my partitions are basic partitions

Comment: ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo parted --list
Model: ATA Hitachi HDS72101 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt

Comment: Number  Start   End     Size   File system  Name                          Flags
 1      1049kB  106MB   105MB  fat32        EFI system partition          boot
 2      106MB   240MB   134MB               Microsoft reserved partition  msftres
 3      240MB   315GB   315GB  ntfs         Basic data partition          msftdata
 4      315GB   629GB   314GB  ntfs         Basic data partition          msftdata
 5      629GB   1000GB  371GB  ntfs         Basic data partition          msftdata

Comment: Warning: Unable to open /dev/sr0 read-write (Read-only file system).  /dev/sr0
has been opened read-only.
Error: Can't have a partition outside the disk!

Comment: sorry dont understand this minimarkdown formatting

Comment: sorry im new with ubuntu and this page ..!

Comment: habs jetzt probiert.. war iwie verwirrend mit dem ganzen / /root /home /swap zeug anscheinend hab ich auch irgendwas falsch gemacht denn er hat zwar installiert und es exisitieren jetzt irgendwelche ubuntu partitionen... trotzdem startet wenn ich beim booten ubuntu auswähle windows...

Comment: @Eiter For clarification Fabby knows German but may not understand every bit of colloquial or abbreviations for "irgendwie" and so do other users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look [here how to efficiently partition a Windows-Ubuntu dual-boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/581902/how-to-efficiently-partition-a-single-windows-ubuntu-dual-boot-disk) before you begin.

**Then:** Delete the partitions you've set aside for Ubuntu using Windows *from Windows* and recreate them *with Ubuntu* during the Ubuntu install with **[something else](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)** in item number 8 "Allocate drive space"

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Comment: @EiterpickelMcWarzeLarry: look at the [**bold link**](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu) again: simpler Installation instructions

Comment: @EiterpickelMcWarzeLarry: Thanks for the acceptance!  Last upvote of today was for you!  **;-)**

Answer (score 0):

You have **Windows 7 on GPT and an EFI system partition**(!?). This usually happens when you replace Windows 8 with 7 but don't change the partition table and are unaware of the differences between legacy and UEFI booting. It confuses the Ubuntu installer that you have an (almost) valid UEFI partition layout but are very likely not booting in UEFI mode.

---

Since your machine obviously shipped with Windows 8 and is UEFI compatible you might want to take a step back and set things up properly. Heres what I recommend:

- Back things up as they are now. (You can copy/backup whole partitions with Ubuntu *Disks* utility.)
- Take Microsoft's upgrade offer and upgrade to Windows 10. You may not have liked Windows 8, but 10 is a step backwards and it completely supports hardware built for Windows 8 where actually 7 didn't. After you got your license for 10 install the UEFI bootloader properly ([hint](https://superuser.com/a/504360/252532): `bcdboot`) or reinstall again from media in UEFI mode.

  - Privacy concerns: Don't use any product with networking capabilities from this manufacturer made in the last 25 years if you have any.
- Install Ubuntu in UEFI mode too.

---

Related:

- SU: [Ubuntu 14.04 installer doesn't show existing partitions](https://superuser.com/a/778813/252532) via ["Install alongside" option missing. How do I install Ubuntu beside Windows using "Something Else"?](https://askubuntu.com/q/163962/40581)

Comment: Ah!  :-) Some Windows 7 systems come with UEFI as well (E.G. "Medion" systems from "Aldi")  He's a beginning user.  I'm trying to keep things as Simple as possible.