# What is the install routine for Common Lisp/ SLIME/SBCL/Quicklisp on Ubuntu?

Tags: emacs, lisp

I'd like to install above recommended Common Lisp package. What is the best routine to install it on Ubuntu?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Ask Ubuntu is not a discussion forum but a Q&A site which means you ask a question and people will (hopefully) answer your question.

Comment: @empedokles: it is possible to ask a question and then answer it yourself to share knowledge.  (Have a look [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/581902/how-to-efficiently-partition-a-single-windows-ubuntu-dual-boot-disk) for an example.)  But you have to actually ask a question first and then answer it...  Please edit the question to be a question and then answer with a ... well... *an answer!*  **;-)**

Answer (score 12):

As I went through the process, I'll sumarize the complete install routine for above recommended Common LISP configuration:

Fire up a terminal:

**Install Emacs (IDE):**

```
sudo apt-get install emacs
```

**Install SBCL (Compiler):**

```
sudo apt-get install sbcl
```

**Install Quicklisp** (Quicklisp is a library manager for Common Lisp.)

This is done by copy-and-pasting all bold commands in the grey box here:
https://www.quicklisp.org/

**Install SLIME by using Qucklisp:**
In the terminal run SBCL:

```
sbcl

(ql:quickload "quicklisp-slime-helper")

(quit)
```

SBCL will warn you about having to edit your ~/.emacs file. Do not ignore it

**Now inside Emacs to start SLIME type:**

```
M-x slime
```

Which is Alt+x slime.

Now you're ready to play with LISP.

Some useful Emacs packages (plugins for Emacs) that were recommended to me are:
Paredit, auto-complete and smartparens

Hope this is of help for anyone.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Synaptics package manager. First search for EMACS and mark for installation. Then do the same for slime. Run the installation and not only is emacs installed but so is slime.