# Migrating from Windows7 to Ubuntu

Tags: partitioning, windows, windows-7, migration

Finally, this is the time to throw Windows to the trash and start working with Ubuntu!
Due to the fact that I had never did it before I would like to ask first in order to avoid further problems.

I have one physical hard-disk divided into 2 partitions C and D.
Windows, naturally, installed on C.
I would like to format C and install a fresh Ubuntu on it.

The question:
Is partition D still will be accessible in Ubuntu, and if yes, how can I refer to it from within Ubuntu?

Comment: It's definitely a good idea to back up your D drive to an external drive first. Ubuntu can install without overwriting your drive, which will likely be mounted as the second partition on the disk, probably referred to as `/dev/sda1`. This question is a great starting place http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu .

Comment: As said everywhere else, it just works and will be available automatically. I just want to add - take the plunge completely. I've done this before. Just delete all the old installers you had laying around, taking up disk space, and clear out the stuff you've been holding on to for a decade or two. Then install and keep poking until you break something. Then fix it, learn something, and soon enough you'll be helping others who were once in the same spot you're in. It looks like you're ready to take that plunge - good luck and the Ubuntu community is huge and awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In Ubuntu there are no drives:** there are just *disks* and *partitions* and they all get *mounted* into the *file system*.

So, before you go ahead and install, boot the LiveDVD and use <kbd>Try Ubuntu</kbd> first!  Then none of your hard disks will be touched and you can still use the full system and try out everything and it'll be obvious to you that all of your existing data can be found under these kinds of icons:

[image: HD Icon]

<sub>(Enlarged for better viewing)</sub>

If you decide after a while to wipe your Windows system partition (your "C:") have a [look here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/581902/how-to-efficiently-partition-a-single-windows-ubuntu-dual-boot-disk) on how to partition a single Windows-Ubuntu dual boot disk.  Lots of the explanations in there will apply to your question.

Comment: I know. I am an ancient inhabitant of StackOverflow. :)

Answer (score 0):

Unlike windows, Ubuntu recognizes the NTFS file system of your D drive. After installing Ubuntu you will be able to mount  that D drive by simply clicking it on its icon which will be shown on left hand side.
Before installing it on your system it will be better if you first try using  Ubuntu via live CD or a live pen drive, which you can easily create using lili(a windows software) and an ISO file for Ubuntu(Can be downloaded from official website of Ubuntu).

Comment: Erm, "Unlike Windows???"  So Windows doesn't recognize NTFS???  `<Scratching head>`

Comment: Pardon me for that, windows does not recognizes Ubuntu formats(i.e, ext4) but Ubuntu does recognize all formats.