# 2 TB hard disk partitioning scheme

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive

I recently bought a 2 TB WD USB hard drive. I want to back up the contents of my Windows and Ubuntu partitions regularly.

Also, in addition i want to store some videos, songs and un-related stuff.

What is the partition scheme you would suggest that could protect my data in case of a crash?

I use ubuntu primarily. I do use windows may be 5 days a month to do random stuff.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to efficiently partition a single Windows-Ubuntu dual boot disk?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/581902/how-to-efficiently-partition-a-single-windows-ubuntu-dual-boot-disk)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to create 4 partitions on the disk - you can use GParted to do it.

Partition 1 - format : ntfs - label : Data - size : 500 GB (for personal things)

Partition 2 - format : ntfs - label : Media - size : 500 GB (for music and videos)

Partition 3 - format : ntfs - label : Rescue - size : 500 GB (for file and system backups)

Partition 4 - format : ntfs - label : System - size : 500 GB (for system related stuff e.g. ISO files)

The size of the partitions should be chosen according your needs ... 500GB is just an example ...

I selected ntfs file system because you can access everything from within Ubuntu and Windows.

Comment: If i use gpart - Does it create gpart table instead of partition table? can gpart table be seen in windows also?

Comment: @S22 : You have to create partitions - install and open GParted in Ubuntu - first shrink (resize) the existing partition, then click on NEW and create the new partitions ... and yes, when you format them with ntfs you can see them in Windows as well ... and if you want to do everything in Windows you can do it with the CLI tool diskpart or with the GUI tool Disk Management. :)

Comment: I am using WD 2TB Ultra. It already comes with backup software (Some folders and executables) factory flashed. If i partition the harddrive. Wont i lose all that?

Comment: @S22 : In case you want to keep this software, just reduce the last (if there is more than one) partition and create new partitions from the unallocated space. :)