# Dual booting Ubuntu Mate on a MBR BIOS system with 4 primary partitions

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, 16.04, mbr

My laptop has, at least according to what I've read on the internet, a MBR system with a legacy BIOS.

Check for whether system is MBR

[image]

Unfortunately it has 4 partitions: a C: drive, two hidden drives called System Reserved and Recovery and a D: drive that has a size equal to the C: drive.

Disk management view of partitions

[image]

I have an Acer TM P-243M and the D: drive is almost completely empty, except for a folder called '24286c2f7bbdd301c6c8b886ef' which seems to contain something called vcredist. I'm not sure if completely wiping out this partition is safe. My system came with Windows 7 Pro pre-installed and I recently upgraded to Windows 10. I want to install Ubuntu Mate. How should I proceed with the partitioning and installation?

Comment: You end up converting your d: drive to an extended partition that can hold many logical partitions. You need at minimum / (root) as ext4 and swap. http://askubuntu.com/questions/149821/my-laptop-already-has-4-primary-partitions-how-can-i-install-ubuntu and: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DualBoot/Partitions and: http://askubuntu.com/questions/581902/how-to-efficiently-partition-a-single-windows-ubuntu-dual-boot-disk

Comment: @oldfred To convert D: to extended, do I need to delete it and then choose allocated space as an extended partition? Or do I simply delete all of D and create logical partitions through Ubuntu installation? What tool should I be using for this?

Comment: I prefer to partition in advance with gparted. You can delete d: as Linux does not recognize Windows partition names and cannot install to NTFS.  Installer should let you create two logical partitions as long as next to each other and then they will be inside an extended partition.

Answer (score 0):

Vcredist is visual c redistributable.system is not affected by removing it.
you could install Ubuntu on drive d from the CD following instructions during install.leave other partitions untouched.no need to partition or format manually.

Comment: So I can simply select the D drive when installing? From what I've read you need to have free space for installation. So wouldn't this entail deleting a partition? I'm sorry, but this is the first time I'm installing Linux.

Comment: You said d drive is free  and further data could be deleted but logical partitions which are actual drives like in this case d,could not be deleted

Comment: D is a primary partition though.

Comment: Download minitool partition wizard from partitionwizard.com and  make d logical partition with it.