# Access denied to delete or rename a folder

Tags: permissions, windows, rename

I use Window10 and I have changed some permission of a drive for a user. It has created a folder with '....' name after these changes in my drive and I can't rename and delete it.

1. What is the folder and why created?
2. How can I rename or delete it?

Comment: Try ask this question in [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/)

Comment: Is this a question about Ubuntu? or about Windows?

Comment: @user535733 Windows

Comment: is there any command in the cmd to solve this problem?

Comment: @SaeidMo7 Please have a look at [What topics can I ask about here](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) in the Help section. Questions about windows is *off topic* on AU. Superuser.com would be a better fit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to efficiently partition a single Windows-Ubuntu dual boot disk?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/581902/how-to-efficiently-partition-a-single-windows-ubuntu-dual-boot-disk) Especially [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/581903/344926) more specifically **Do the administration of complex rights always on the host system!**

Answer (score 3):

You can delete folder using below methods:

**Linux Method**

Since you have Windows 10 there's an app in Microsoft Store called as Ubuntu. That's actually terminal of Ubuntu that let you run Linux commands.

[image]

1. Open the app and configure it.
2. After configuring, terminate it and search for Ubuntu in apps.
3. Open app. It will open cmd like interface. Type `sudo su` and type password which you set while configuring the app
4. Navigate to the folder destination and use `rm -r "Folder_Name"`. For more info how to navigate in Ubuntu Terminal, see screenshot below.

[image]

Since I use both Linux and Window, I'll suggest you to use Ubuntu method. Its a powerful method.

Comment: what is 'sudo' ?

Comment: I have not this application. do you give me any link  that i download it?

Comment: @AmanMittal we do not provide windows answers so I remove a little bit of your answer. The part about Linux is interesting though even though the correct way to act was to close vote it as off topic, not about Ubuntu.