# Cannot change permissions of partition

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, permissions, kubuntu

I cannot write anything to my Windows partition. Trying below command does not help.

```
$ sudo chmod 777 /media/pi/Windows 
[sudo] password for pi: 
chmod: changing permissions of '/media/pi/Windows': Read-only file system
```

But when I do `ls -l /media/pi/Windows` I get `drwxrwxrwx` for all folders and `-rwxrwxrwx` for all files.
[image]
I am using Ubuntu 18.04
`Codename:       bionic`

Comment: What is the mount command you used to mount the device (or `fstab` entry) and the output to `lsb_release --code`?

Comment: You cannot change ownership & permissions on NTFS formatted partitions. They only have settings based on mount. If issue is it really Windows hibernation is on? https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Comment: Actually I am able to mount and read the Windows partition but cannot write onto it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to efficiently partition a single Windows-Ubuntu dual boot disk?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/581902/how-to-efficiently-partition-a-single-windows-ubuntu-dual-boot-disk)

Comment: Are you sure that when leaving Windows you have [shut it down completely](https://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-quickly-shut-down-windows-10/)? - if your symptoms are that paste, rename, delete options in file manager context menu are absent, most probably that's the cause