# How can I access my LVM partition from Windows 10?

Tags: dual-boot, drivers, windows, filesystem, lvm

I have 2 SSD drives in my laptop.  One has Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, and the other has Windows 10.  I am able to boot into either one separately by telling the BIOS which drive to boot.  I have some files on my Ubuntu drive that I would like to access from Windows.  Normally, I could just install ext2fsd and everything would be fine.  But my Ubuntu drive is formatted using LVM.  Is there any way to access those files from Windows?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to efficiently partition a single Windows-Ubuntu dual boot disk?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/581902/how-to-efficiently-partition-a-single-windows-ubuntu-dual-boot-disk)

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of answers about on the internet, but it seems that Windows does not support LVM2 (or at least not very well)

You could try http://www.chrysocome.net/virtualvolumes --or--https://roshanbook.wordpress.com/2012/02/04/accessing-lvm2-in-windows/

The second link describes creating an Ubuntu VM in Virtual box, using that Virtual machine to mount the LVM partitions, and then sharing the directories through Samba.

Comment: you are giving the blog post from 2012 in 2019, unlikely the situation haven't changed since then, this solution will be outdated

Comment: @Suncatcher That could be true but at this time, in 2022 Windows still can't nativly read ext4 file systems.  Asking to look at LVM on top of that difficulty is asking quite a bit.  There are a couple of third party applications that run in Windows to examine ext4 file systems that I can find today, with a casual search, but not LVM